# How to solve circular package dependencies

Tags: java, architecture, packages

I am refactoring a large codebase where most of the classes are located in one package. For better modularity, I am creating subpackages for each functionality.

I remember learning somewhere that a package dependency graph should not have loops, but I don't know how to solve the following problem: `Figure` is in package `figure`, `Layout` is in package `layout`, `Layout` requires the figure to perform layout, so package `layout` depends on package `figure`. But on the other hand, a `Figure` can contain other `Figure`s inside it, having its own `Layout`, which makes package `figure` dependent on package `layout`.

I have though of some solutions, like creating a `Container`interface which `Figure` implements and putting it in the `Layout` package. Is this a good solution? Any other possibilities?

Thanks

Comment: It is modules (e.g. different Jars) can not have circular dependencies. Packages CAN and often HAVE circular depenencies, as long as they belong to the same module.

Comment: @lorus So this is not a design problem?

Comment: No, it is not. Packages are normally just a namespaces.This may change only when they used for something else, e.g. to change their contents visibility in OSGi environment. Don't bother otherwise.

Comment: Note that many authorities condemn cyclical dependencies, and sometimes with good reason, but before you blindly refactor, you should make sure one of those reasons actually applies to you. If the package structure is giving you no trouble, and you cannot, in good conscience, see why it would in the future, don't change something so fundamental just to satisfy abstract architectural values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should think about [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)

You basically define an interface for your `Layout` which is located somewhere near your Layout class in an own package so you would have an implementation package and a public interface package - for instance call it `Layoutable` (I don't know if that's proper English). Now - Layout won't implement that interface but the `Figure` class. 
Likewise you would create an interface for Figure that's `Drawable` for instance.

So

```
my.public.package.Layoutable
my.implementation.package.Layout
my.public.package.Drawable
my.implementation.package.Figure
```

Now - Figure implements Layoutable and thus can be used by Layout and (I'm not sure yet if that is what you wanted) - Layout implements Drawable and can be drawn in a Figure. The point is, that the class that exposes some service makes it available by an interface (here: Layout and Layoutable) - the class that wants to use that service has to implement the interface.

Then you would have something like a creator object that binds both together. So the creator would have a dependency to `Layout` as well as to `Figure`, but `Layout` and `Figure` themselves would be independent.

That's the rough idea.

An excellent source for solutions to this problems is the book [Java Application Architecture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321247132) by Kirk Knoernschild.

Comment: Isn't this the same as the `Container` interface as suggested in the question?

Comment: Yes - and no - I wouldn't put them both in the same package as I stated. And there wasn't much theory behind it. And in this case it is not sufficient to do it one side, you'll have to do it on both sides. Alright?

Comment: Oops, I missed the bit in the original question about `Container` going in the same package as `Layout`. That wouldn't work, whereas your solution would.

Comment: ah - ok - I seemed to have missed the part with the Container though when I was hacking - should have named it Container ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too clear on what a `Figure` is, but perhaps it should be in the same package as `Layout`?

Your proposed `Container` interface solution wouldn't work - unless you put the `Container` interface in a 3rd package then you would still have a circular dependency between the two packages. See [michael_s's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/186944/46461) for something which would work.

Another thing, as others have mentioned - it will probably never be an issue. You're only going to run into problems in future if `Figure` and `Layout` want to be in separate *modules*. You can deal with this if and when that becomes necessary, but given that the two classes seem quite closely related this seems highly unlikely.