# Packaging structure of Java collections (java.util) - why does Iterable sit in java.lang?

Tags: java, api, packages, collections

As per the below diagram, except for interface `Iterable`, all the remaining constructs (interface / class / abstract class) sit in same package `java.util`

[image]

Why does `Iterable` sit in `java.lang`package?

*Note: The intention is to understand the packaging aspect of java programming.*

Comment: wonder why this is tagged [tag:java8], all APIs asked about here are much older. Iterable was introduced in Java version 1.5, collections framework in 1.2

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As explained in its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), the purpose of `Iterable` is to **support particular language syntax**:

> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the "foreach" statement

As such, it belongs to the [lang package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html), which

> Provides classes that are fundamental to the design of the Java programming language.

---

Other classes at the diagram **belong to [JCF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html)** and hence, are in the [util package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) which

> Contains the collections framework...

Comment: +1. I think, though, that `Iterator` should ideally also be in `java.lang`, since `Iterable` is. Of course, it has to be in `java.util` for backward-compatibility reasons (it had been introduced in the JDK long before the "foreach" construct gave it a role in the language proper).

Comment: @ruakh Iterator is convenient, but was probably considered too specific (method selection and naming) to go to "fundamental" package. Think of its predecessor [Enumeration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html), which eventually turned out not as convenient as originally thought, it was prudent that it didn't go to lang package

Comment: My point was not that it's convenient, but that the language proper now depends on it. (Note that, aside from the dependency of `Iterable` on `Iterator `, the `java.lang` package does not generally depend on classes in `java.util`.)

Comment: @ruakh I see. That's a very good point, thanks. I can understand why API designers wanted Iterable to expose "an object that performs iteration" but the way they have chosen to do this doesn't feel elegant

Answer (score 6):

Because a lot of things implement the interface [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) or extend it as a sub interface.

The implementing classes are:

- java.util

  - AbstractCollection
  - AbstractList
  - AbstractQueue
  - AbstractSequentialList
  - AbstractSet
  - ...
  - concurrent

    - ArrayBlockingQueue
    - ConcurrentLinkedDeque
    - ...
- java.beancontext

  - BeanContextServicesSupport
  - BeanContextSupport
  - ...
- java.sql

  - BatchUpdateException
  - DataTruncation
  - ...
- javax.management

  - AttributeList
- javax.print.attribute.standard

  - JobStateReasons
  - ...
- ...

This is a huge list. And it touches on all sorts of packages out there.

Furthermore, you want to minimize [circular package dependencies](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/186921/40980).  If a class in package A depends on a class in package B which depends on a class in package A, you've got a circular dependency.  They're not always bad that they exist - but they lead to other circular dependencies and that can be a bad thing.  Its not bad by itself, but it is a design smell that indicates that the coupling between two classes or packages is too tight. It is the start of technical debt accumulating.

The solution to this is to say "yes, the Iterable interface is something that is depended on in a wide variety of classes and packages throughout the entirety of the java and javax structure.  It should be in the most base of the language libraries - java.lang."

And that is where you will find it.

Related reading:

- [Java Dependency Analysis and Modularization](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/java/3135-java-dependency-analysis-and-modularisation.html)
- [Avoid cyclic dependencies between packages](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=60752360)